# What is the cardinality of this infinite group?

Tags: solution-verification, cardinals

I need to the detriment the cardinality of a group and prove why.

The group:

```
A = {The group of all real numbers in the range between 0 and 1, where the digits can only be ones and zeroes, and after each zero comes a one}
```

At first I thought this is `א`, and was planning to prove it using the good old technique of picking one where there is zero, and zero where there is one.

But then I came up with the following function:

```
f:A ---> Z
f(x) = {
 if the first digit after the point is zero, conversion of the binary digits after the point in x (excluding the first zero) into a decimal number

 if the first digit after the point is one, conversion of the binary digits after the point in x into a decimal number, multiplied by minus one
}
```

This function seems to be reversible, and since `|Z|` is `א0`, `|A|` should be `א0` as well. on the other hand, if proving using the method I intended to use, the result is that `|A|` is `א`.

Which one is it, and why?

Comment: What is "$\aleph$"? Do you mean $2^{\aleph_0}$? (Incidentally, $\mathbb{Z}$ has cardinality $\aleph_0$, not $0_\alpha$ as you've written, and the set in question is not a **group**.) Also, in general you should use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to include symbols in the question.

Comment: @NoahSchweber by א0 I mean listable infininitys

Comment: As to the question itself, the error is that your process does not in fact yield an integer: e.g. consider $0.10101010...$.

Comment: " by א0 I mean listable infininitys" The notation is "$\aleph_0$" (in LaTeX: "\$\aleph_0\$").

Comment: @NoahSchweber Why is this a problem? the function will just yield a number with infinitely many digits, just as 1010101 is......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cardinality of your set is that of the continuum, because it's basically the set of all infinite sequences composed of the strings $1$ and $01$.

As mentioned in the comments, the problem with your proof idea is that $f(x)$ is not always an integer. If you would like to interpret $f(x)$ as simply an infinite binary sequence, then that's fine, but then the injectivity of $f$ gives you no grounds on which to claim $A$ is countable.

Comment: And how do I prove this is a continuum? what reversible function there is from this group to R?

Comment: @avivgood2 It's well known that the set of binary sequences has the cardinality of the continuum, because each real number has a binary representation. The point is that by treating "01" as a single element, you can see that your set is in bijection with the set of *all* binary sequences. By the way, you should really stop using the word "group" (which means something else) and say "set".

Comment: I understand. using 01 as 0 and 1 as 1 can create binary number that can represent every decimal number. but how do I represent non integers? and negative numbers?

Comment: @avivgood2 This answer basically addresses how to show that $A$ is equinumerous to the set of all binary sequences $B$. To show that $B$ is equinumerous to $\mathbb R$ is a little bit delicate for the reasons you mentioned, but it's a standard result so you can probably find the details online, probably on this site.